# Two pennants moving one pixel at a time (racing) towards the finish line with a random probability?

Tags: java

Just like in the title. I am trying to follow the online resources for Penn's CIS 110 class and teach myself basic programming skills during the summer but I am already having issues with the first problem set.

Essentially, I am supposed to write a program where two pennants will move randomly and independently towards the finish line.

I know the independent movement means that there are four cases

a) the first pennant moves, but the second one doesn't.

b) the second one moves, but the first one doesn't.

c) Both move.

d) Neither moves.

Once one pennant crosses the finish line, the animation should stop, and my program should draw text in the window indicating which pennant won.

What I have so far is position my start and finish line, and my pennants but I am not sure how to make the pennants move along the straight line with a random probability?

Any help would be much appreciated since I am pretty much clueless on how to go about animating them. This what I have so far:

```
    boolean pennWins = false; //has penn won the race?
    boolean princetonWins = false; //has princeton won the race

    PennDraw.setCanvasSize(512, 512);

    double rx = 0.15, ry = 0.8, rz = .2;


    PennDraw.enableAnimation(10);


     while (!pennWins && !princetonWins) {
        PennDraw.clear();
        PennDraw.setPenColor(PennDraw.BLACK);
        PennDraw.setPenRadius(.005);
        PennDraw.line(.03, 0, .03, 1);
        PennDraw.line(.65, 0, .65, 1); 
        PennDraw.picture(rx, ry,"penn.png");
        PennDraw.picture(rx, rz,"princeton.png");
```

Comment: Like writing a `move()` method with a `Math.random()` to choose if your "pennant" moves or not ? Plus, without seeing any code we can't help you much ... show us what you tried so far ! (I'm adding that it's really not necessary to have "cases", just use a random function to choose if a pennant moves or not)

Comment: Thanks for edits and for your help! I just added what I have so far. I am totally new at this so I'm not really sure how to approach things/think about them